# How to group two fields together in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

say I have a sql that currently returns all soccer players who has played during each years. Like so:

```
  name       year      goals
john        2010        1 
john        2006        2
john        2006        8
fred        2006        1
```

But I want the result to be grouped by the years they played, but do not compress player names if they are from different years, like so:

```
 name     year      goals
john      2010       1
john      2006       10        <--- This is compressed, but there are still 2 johns
fred      2006       1              since they are from different years
```

say I have done this so far.

```
(select name, year, goals
from table) as T
```

If I just do

```
select *
from
  (select name, year, goals
  from table) as T 
group by year;
```

Fred will disappear, but if I do "group by name", there are only 1 john left. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name, year, sum(goals) as totalgoals
from table
group by name, year
```

Comment: would `group by name, year` then look for rows that have identical `name` and `year` fields and then AND ONLY THEN group them into one? Would that then mean that by doing `group by name, year, goals` in the above example the returned table will be the same as the original table?

Comment: @Webeng Yes, the "groups" are all rows with the same "name-year" combination. If you added goals, it would return all rows with the same "name-year-goals". So in the example, it would return the original table, but if two of the rows were duplicates (ie two john-2010-1 rows) it would combine those and just show "john-2010-2"

Comment: awesome, and I am assuming the order doesn't matter correct?

Comment: @Webeng That's correct, rows can be in any order, they'll still be grouped.

Comment: I meant the order of the columns in `group by [column1] [column2]` hahah

Comment: @Webeng Oh, yeah, grouped by columns are treated as a single "set",  order within the set doesn't matter.